# Fabric js clip background color

Tags: fabricjs

I have a custom clipping, not default one. In my case I want to see image that out of clipping area and watermark. All works fine, but I can't change background color of empty area behind my image.

Here's working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0ffa71/1/).

I've tried to set `c.backgroundColor = 'red'` or `c.overlayColor = 'red'`, but it doesnt work.

**EDIT:** example of solution could be found in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0ffa71/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It­*'s* not working because, you have set the **`globalCompositeOperation`** property to **`destination-atop`** for the image object, which changes the drawing destination of the background color. There is no need to set this property for the image object at all.

Here is the working version of your code ...

```js
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
c.setBackgroundColor('white'); //set canvas background color

var clip = {
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   right: c.getWidth() - 100,
   bottom: c.getHeight() - 100
}
var rb = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 H ' + c.getWidth() + ' V ' + clip.top + ' H ' + clip.left + ' V ' + clip.bottom + ' H ' + clip.right + ' V ' + clip.top + ' H ' + c.getWidth() + ' V ' + c.getHeight() + ' H 0 Z', {
   left: 0,
   top: 0,
   fill: 'rgba(100,50,31,0.3)'
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
   left: clip.right - 40,
   top: clip.bottom - 40,
   radius: 40,
   fill: 'bisque'
});
var g = new fabric.Group([rb, circle], {
   left: 0,
   top: 0
});
c.setOverlayImage(g);
fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/png;base64,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', function(fimg) {
   c.add(fimg.set({
      left: clip.left - 50,
      top: clip.top - 50,
      //globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-atop' //<-- do not set this
   }));
   c.setActiveObject(c.item(0));
})
c.renderAll();

fabric.Canvas.prototype.cropImage = function(format, quality, x, y, width, height) {
   var canvasEl = this.lowerCanvasEl || this.upperCanvasEl;

   this.deactivateAll().renderAll(true);

   var printEl = canvasEl;

   // Only use extra canvas if any optional param is given
   if (x || y || width || height) {
      // Defaults
      x = x || 0;
      y = y || 0;
      width = width || canvasEl.width - x;
      height = height || canvasEl.height - y;

      // create printCanvas if necessary
      if (!fabric.printCanvas)
         fabric.printCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

      printEl = fabric.printCanvas;

      // Calculate spaces over canvas bounds
      var d = {
         left: (x > 0) ? 0 : -x,
         top: (y > 0) ? 0 : -y,
         right: (x + width < canvasEl.width) ? 0 : (width + x) - canvasEl.width,
         bottom: (y + height < canvasEl.height) ? 0 : (height + y) - canvasEl.height
      };

      // Print section
      printEl.width = width;
      printEl.height = height;
      printEl.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvasEl,
         x + d.left, y + d.top, width - d.right - d.left, height - d.bottom - d.top,
         d.left, d.top, width - d.right - d.left, height - d.bottom - d.top);

   }

   var data = (fabric.StaticCanvas.supports('toDataURLWithQuality')) ? printEl.toDataURL('image/' + format, quality) : printEl.toDataURL('image/' + format);

   this.contextTop && this.clearContext(this.contextTop);
   this.renderAll();
   return data;
};

$('#clip').click(function() {
   window.open(c.cropImage('png', 75, clip.left, clip.top, clip.right - clip.left, clip.bottom - clip.top));
});
```

```css
canvas{outline: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<button id="clip">
   Clip
</button>
```

and a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h10g69c1/)**

Comment: I'm using `globalCompositeOperation` for mixing image color with outer region fill color. If you set path's fill to `rgba(255,255,0,0.5)` (yellow), you will see that presented image will change color outside middle region. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0ffa71/2/)

Comment: Yes I see, but, it works the same with or without setting `globalCompositeOperation`

Comment: But background color in this case will change both outer and inner region color. Try to set in your fiddle `c.setBackgroundColor('yellow')` and path's fil to `rgba(255,255,255,0.3)`. I expected yellow background for inner region, but I've got for both.

Comment: Well, I think I've found some trick. Set `backgroundImage` with filled rectangle inside: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st0ffa71/3/)

Comment: Great !! Cheers !!